# I want to update array of objects which include datetime field in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hi I am new to mongodb trying to update date fields in  array of objects.

Below I have mentioned my model and I have mentioned my query, it's working for start_time and end_time but not update array of objects but I need to update dateTime field which is in objects in time_slots array.

These are my mongodb sample documents:

```
db={
  "teacher": [
    {
      "_id": "6434cf",
      "start_time": ISODate("2023-03-22T07:00:25.787Z"),
      "end_time": ISODate("2023-03-22T10:00:35.604Z"),
      "duration": "15min",
      "time_slots": [
        {
          "sl_no": 1,
          "dateTime": ISODate("2023-03-22T06:30:25.787Z")
        },
        {
          "sl_no": 2,
          "dateTime": ISODate("2023-03-22T06:45:25.787Z")
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "6434ctd",
      "start_time": ISODate("2023-03-23T07:00:25.787Z"),
      "end_time": ISODate("2023-03-23T10:00:35.604Z"),
      "duration": "20min",
      "time_slots": [
        {
          "sl_no": 1,
          "dateTime": ISODate("2023-03-23T06:30:25.787Z")
        },
        {
          "sl_no": 2,
          "dateTime": ISODate("2023-03-23T06:50:25.787Z")
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My query for updating start_time and end_time

```
updateOne(
  { _id:id  },
  [{ 
    $set: {
      start_time: { $dateAdd: { startDate: "$start_time", unit: "minute", amount: hours}},
      end_time: { $dateAdd: { startDate: "$end_time", unit: "minute", amount: hours } }
    }
  }]
)
```

this is my desired output if a user wants to delay 1 hour

```
{
  "_id": "6434cf" ,
  "start_time":ISODate("2023-03-22T08:00:25.787Z"),
  "end_time":ISODate("2023-03-22T11:00:35.604Z"),
  
  "duration": "15min",
  "time_slots": [
    {
      "sl_no": 1,
      "dateTime": ISODate("2023-03-22T07:30:25.787Z")
    },
    {
      "sl_no": 2 ,
      "dateTime":ISODate("2023-03-22T07:45:25.787Z")
    }
  ],
}
```

it should increase 1 hour in start_time, end_time and in dateTime filed in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `$map`:

```
db.teacher.updateOne(
  {_id: id},
  [
    {$set: {
      start_time: {$dateAdd: {startDate: "$start_time", unit: "minute", amount: hours}},
      end_time: {$dateAdd: {startDate: "$end_time", unit: "minute", amount: hours}},
      time_slots: {$map: {
          input: "$time_slots",
          in: {
            sl_no: "$$this.sl_no",
            dateTime: {$dateAdd: {
                startDate: "$$this.dateTime", unit: "minute", amount: hours
            }}
          }
      }}
    }}
  ]
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_HFJo6WzNpx)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response @nimrod serok. it works as expected.     can you help me if dateTime field is in string if it contain only time how can we update that ????

Comment: now = "dateTime":ISODate("2023-03-22T07:45:25.787Z"), if it will be like this ="dateTime":"07:45 AM" , then how can we update that

Comment: On this case you can use `$dateFromString`, but I strongly recommend you to keep the current format of `ISODate`